# How to open the modal popup using a link, instead of button with passing id to retrieve data

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

How do I pop open the modal using a link, instead of a button? I don't want the action to be a button, I want it to be a  href link, The code is provided below. Buttons suck, links rule.

As of right now, I have the code as a button to open the modal, I have two tables, the first one is services category and the second one is services, when I select services category i want to open modal and view the services that have the same category. I just want to open the modal using a regular link that I have for my main menu, so as you can see, I don’t want to put a button in the main menu, because the main menu has links that are styled for the menu.

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT  * FROM services_categories    
        ORDER BY `services_categories`.`services_category_id` Desc ";
        $count=$dbo->prepare($query);
        $count->execute();
        $no=$count->rowCount();
        if($no > 0 ){ 
            echo "
            <div >
            <table  class='responstable responstable2 ' ><tr><th >Service Name</th></tr>";
            foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){
            echo "<tr><td>$row[services_category_id]</td><td>$row[services_category_name]</td>
                     <td><input type='button' name='view' value='view' id=' $row[services_category_id]' class='btn btn-info btn-xs view_data' /></td>
                    </tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            }else {
            echo " No records found ";
                }
         ?>



<div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Service</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" id="service_detail">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="" 
data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
event.preventDefault();  
});

$(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
//$('#dataModal').modal();
var services_category_id = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
url:"select.php",
method:"POST",
data:{services_category_id:services_category_id},
success:function(data){
$('#service_detail').html(data);
$('#dataModal').modal('show');
}
});
});
}); 
</script>
<?php include("db_connect.php"); header('Content-Type:text/html; 
charset=utf-8');
if(isset($_POST["services_category_id"]))
{
 $output = '';
 $query = "SELECT  * FROM services  left JOIN services_categories 
 ON (services.services_category_id = 
 services_categories.services_category_id)  
 WHERE services.services_category_id  
 ='".$_POST["services_category_id"]."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

 $count=$dbo->prepare($query);
        $count->execute();
        $no=$count->rowCount();
        if($no > 0 ){ 
            echo "
            <div >
            <table  class='responstable responstable2 ' >   
                <tr>
                  <th >services</th>
                </tr>";
            foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row){
            echo "<tr><td>$row[service_name]</td>
            </tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            }else {
            echo " No records found ";
                }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The modal opens when any element with the `view_data` class is clicked.

If I understood you correctly all you would need to do is replace:

```
<input type='button' name='view' value='view' id=' $row[services_category_id]' class='btn btn-info btn-xs view_data' />
```

With:

```
<a href='#' id='$row[services_category_id]' class='view_data'>Whatever text you want</a>
```